# How to add shadow to ImageView?

Tags: ios, swift

Problem - How do I add shadow to ImageView that looks like the attached?

[image]

What I've done so far

```
        imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 5


        imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Doesn't look like the attached. Can someone please help?

Comment: if you want the corner radius for the shadow, use the shadowPath

Comment: By doesn't look like the above, do you mean the shadow isn't visible?